# Digitizing overlapping hatched range maps

Tags: qgis, r, digitizing

So I have a book of range maps for species within a taxon. As they are presented, many of them are hatched (or stippled, etc.) and overlap ("cross-hatching" shows two species coexisting in the same spot). How would I go about digitizing and extracting the range maps accurately and separate for every species?

Also could this be done with non-ESRI software, preferably R?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you want to do this _automatically_, or are you looking for directions on georeferencing / digitising manually? p.s. a scanned image would be helpful here!

Comment: You can do georeferencing of images with QGIS, and then manually digitise the regions as new vector features over the image. QGIS is the leading open source cross-platform GIS. If you want to do this manually then its a bit of a tricky image processing job, probably, since most maps in books have lots of extra cartography (labels, roads...) over the regions of interest which messes up simple algorithms. Can we see a sample?

Comment: @Simbamangu Sorry it took so long to reply! Here is a link to a couple examples: http://imgur.com/a/bjEjA

Comment: @Spacedman I edited in a URL to some examples. Sorry it took so long to reply!

Comment: This looks like a tough one ... it would be very difficult to programmatically distinguish between the state/national boundaries and the various kinds of hatching, for one thing, let alone the differences between hatching types themselves!

Comment: @Simbamangu Hmmm...Would I be able to use a program like GIMP to extract the distribution as a shape file? Though I do wonder about large blobs in the middle of the continent without any georefencing points. Thanks for all the help! I appreciate it considerably!

Comment: There are plenty of georeferencing points on the images - all the state and national boundary data is there (if you know the projection/CRS of the image). If you have some ideas using GIMP, play around and then edit this post with some results and show where you’ve reached.